# Checkboxes binding in AngualrJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I have two checkboxes , one with Data Binding and other one is without Data Binding.As you can see in the code below.

```
<html ng-app="notesApp">
    <head><title>Notes App</title></head>
    <body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
        <div>
            <h2>What are your favorite sports?</h2>
            <div ng-repeat="sport in ctrl.sports">
                <label ng-bind="sport.label"></label>
                <div>
                    With Binding:
                    <input type="checkbox"  data-ng-true-value="YES" data-ng-false-value="NO" >
                </div>
                <div>
                    Using ng-checked:
                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked='sport.selected === "YES"'>

                </div>
                <div>
                    Current state : {{sport.selected}}
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('notesApp',[])
            .controller('MainCtrl',[function(){
                var self = this;
                self.sports = [
                    {label:'Basketball',selected: 'YES'},
                    {label:'Cricket',selected:'NO'},
                    {label:'Soccer',selected:'NO'},
                    {label:'Swimming',selected:'YES'}
                ];

            }]);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When i click on the checkbox of 'with data binding', it should bind and reflect the value in current state label.But it is not happening.Why ?.Can someone help Please .

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ng-model`? How is AngularJS going to know what the `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` should represent? According to the docs it's required: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 problems I found with your code:

1. You forgot `ng-model`
2. You should specify a constant for `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value`, by specifying `YES` angular will look for a `YES` property on the scope, write `'YES'` instead

Updated working plnkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/rnYRUpIICC7HAKdKXf3i?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="notesApp">

<head>
    <title>Notes App</title>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
<div>
    <h2>What are your favorite sports?</h2>
    <div ng-repeat="sport in ctrl.sports">
        <label ng-bind="sport.label"></label>
        <div>
            With Binding:
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="sport.selected" data-ng-true-value="'YES'" data-ng-false-value="'NO'" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Using ng-checked:
            <input type="checkbox" data-ng-checked="sport.selected === 'YES'" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Current state : {{sport.selected}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('notesApp',[])
            .controller('MainCtrl',[function(){
                var self = this;
                self.sports = [
                    {label:'Basketball',selected: 'YES'},
                    {label:'Cricket',selected:'NO'},
                    {label:'Soccer',selected:'NO'},
                    {label:'Swimming',selected:'YES'}
                ];

            }]);

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

EDIT: As @g00glen00b mentioned, before angular 1.3 `ng-true-value` accepted only constant values, so in case you're not using angular 1.3 or later you don't have to wrap `YES` in quotes.

Comment: Noteworthy, before AngularJS 1.3, `ng-true-value` was only accepting constant values (no expressions). So if he's using AngularJS 1.2 or lower, `ng-true-value="YES"` will work.

Comment: @NexusDuck ..Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @ArjunSarthi Glad to help :)

Comment: @ArjunSarthi If you feel that this answer solved your question, you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: @NexusDuck...I am sorry ..I tried to upvote but ,it is saying that i need to have more credit or something...is there any other ways i can mark it.I am kind of new to this.

Comment: @ArjunSarthi Correct, you need 15 reputation to upvote answers. But I'm pretty sure you can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the 'V' sign on the left

Comment: @ArjunSarthi Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

The `data-ng-true-value` and `data-ng-false-value` are used when you're using the `input[checkbox]` directive, but they do require `ngModel`, as you can see in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D) (note that `ng-model` is not in square brackets).

Without providing the model, AngularJS has no way to know where to apply the true/false value to. Adding `data-ng-model` does seem to work, as you can see in the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eLure8tb/).

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="sport.selected"
    data-ng-true-value="YES"
    data-ng-false-value="NO" />
```

Also, please note that when using AngularJS 1.3 or higher, the values of `ng-true-value` and `ng-false-value` should be an expression rather than a constant value. Which means that for AngularJS 1.3 and higher you'll have to replace it by `ng-true-value="'YES'"`, for example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="sport.selected"
    data-ng-true-value="'YES'"
    data-ng-false-value="'NO'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not applying "data-ng-model" attribute to the the checkbox. Please replace your "With binding" check box code from below:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="sport.selected" data-ng-true-value="YES" data-ng-false-value="NO" >
```